# World map picture to globe

Tags: coordinate-system

i have 26 pictures of the globe and i want to bound them. How can i proceed to abtain a flatworld map? it looks circa like this but in 26 pieces.
[map](http://www.justglobes.co.uk/images/illuminated_globe_map.jpg)

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2):

You could try georeferencing the image onto a map that has a sinusoidal projection, and then reproject to mercator, but unless you know all the parameters for the projection and transformation there's going to be distortion and gaps.

This site may be of interest: http://www.rmg.co.uk/make-your-own/globe

as may this: http://www.progonos.com/furuti/MapProj/Dither/ProjInt/projInt.html

and there is a paper on myriahedral projections here: http://www.win.tue.nl/~vanwijk/myriahedral/CAJ103.pdf